# Objective or objectively

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which is correct:

1. Objective negative review
2. Objectively negative review
3. Negative (objective) review

Comment: To improve the question, do include some context (who are you writing to? what are you trying to say) and some self analysis (why do you have a doubt about this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're all grammatical, and mean slightly different things.

An objective negative review (which might also be written "objective, negative review") means a negative review which is also an objective review.

An objectively negative review means a negative review where the judgment of it as negative is objective.

It is unclear just what your third option means: putting "objective" in brackets suggests that that its being objective is either less important, or is obvious and doesn't really need to be stated.